# Neo4j match nodes with similiraity property(array)

Tags: arrays, neo4j

I have a nodes of movies with property like:genre,writers,languages(arrays of string)

I want to get all the nodes with similar array property,and the similarity percent

for example,for genre property:

Movie1:Crime, Drama, Myster

Movie2:Drama

33% of similarity

in addition

in addition,i want a query that returns all the movies with at least one common genre
writers,languages

I know that I have to use collect function,but how i compare the arrays

for example:
Movie1:Crime, Drama, Myster

Movie2:Crime, Myster

Movie3:Myster,Comedy

Movie4:Comedy

Group1:Movie1,Movie2,Movie3

Group2:Movie3,Movie4

Comment: And how far did you go?

Comment: i dont know how to work with arrays,how to compare arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`REDUCE`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reduce) to count the intersections:

```
WITH 
  ['Drama','Crime','Mystery'] as genre1,
  ['Drama'] as genre2
WITH
  genre1, 
  genre2,
  CASE WHEN size(genre1)>size(genre2) 
       THEN size(genre1) 
       ELSE size(genre2)
  END as maxSize, 
  REDUCE(acc=0, 
         genre in genre1 
         | acc + CASE WHEN genre in genre2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) as similarity
RETURN genre1, 
       genre2, 
       100.0 * similarity / maxSize as similarity
```

Or you can use [`apoc.coll.intersection`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions) function from [`APOC library`](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures):

```
WITH 
  ['Drama','Crime','Mystery'] as genre1,
  ['Drama'] as genre2
WITH
  genre1, 
  genre2,
  apoc.coll.max([size(genre1), size(genre2)]) as maxSize,
  apoc.coll.intersection(genre1, genre2) as similarity
RETURN genre1, 
       genre2, 
       100.0 * size(similarity) / maxSize as similarity
```

If you just want to find the nodes that intersect at least one genre:

```
MATCH (M:Movie)
UNWIND M.genres as genre
WITH genre, 
     M
     ORDER BY id(M) ASC
WITH genre, 
     collect(M) as movies
RETURN distinct movies as movies
```

Comment: thank you i have one more request ,,i want a query that returns all the movies with at least one common genre writers,languages